# ActionMode menu icon background

Tags: android

I am using the ActionMode via:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list_context, menu);
        this.mActionMode = mode;
        return true;
    }
```

And my resource file menu_list_context is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/discard_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
    android:title="delete"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

The style for my ActionBar is:

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

where `<color name="background_holo_light">#dddddd</color>`.

With these settings, my ActionBar under ActionMode looks like this:

[image]

The icon has the background of my ActionBar (holo light), but the ActionMode background seems white. How can I fix the icon background to have the ActionMode background (including the blue bottom line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [Action Bar Style Generator](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjgilfelt.github.io%2Fandroid-actionbarstylegenerator%2F&ei=OtrxVIDLHJaLuAToroLADA&usg=AFQjCNF8xXe4vR-04szdfH1dS1vt5KLXxA). This is the only way I know of to get exact `ActionBar` styles that actually works.